# Is Spark good for automatically running statistical analysis script in many nodes for a speedup?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have a Python script that runs statistical analysis and trained deep learning models on input data. The data size is fairly small (~5Mb) however the speed is slow due to the complexity of the analysis script. I wonder if it would be possible to use Spark to run my script in different nodes on a cluster so that I can gain a speedup. Basically, I want to divide the input data into many subsets and run the analysis script in parallel. Is Spark a good tool for this purpose? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you integrate your deep learning model into your pyspark pipeline and use [partitioning](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-partitionby-example/), you can expect a speedup in the runtime. Without code, it's hard to make specific recommendations, but [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/distributed-deep-learning-pipelines-with-pyspark-and-keras-a3a1c22b9239) is a good place to start.